# Adding points along line in QGIS based on heading change?

Tags: qgis, point, heading

I have a number of point to point lines in QGIS as vector layers. They are not straight lines and have multiple points along them where the heading/direction of the line changes.

I am trying to find a way to automatically plot a data point at each of the heading changes along the line and then also be able to interrogate the distance between each of them.

Can anyone advise if this is possible please?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the native [extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=extract%20vertices#extract-vertices) tool does what you're looking for. Hand it a line- or polygon-layer, run it, and you get the vertices of that line, including the heading of the line beyond this point and its distance along the line.

Comment: Thats great, thank you very much, that worked a treat.